# How to return a javascript output back to a python's http requests using flask

Tags: javascript, python, flask, python-requests

I want to create a flask app that processes a video file that the users send through python HTTP request and return the resulting value back. my problem is that I need to use a javascript library and I don't know how to return the javascript results back to the flask app.

I embed the image into template.html which runs my javascript file. The problem is I don't know how to return this variable back to the POST request. Is this even doable? And if not what is the best way to pass javascript result back to flask.

python call

```
r = requests.post('URLForFlaskServer/processFile', files=files,)
```

flask app

```
@app.route('/processFile', methods=['POST'])
def process_file():
    file = request.files['image_file']
    f = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], "videoFile.mp4")
    file.save(f)
    render_template('template.html', filename=f)
    return  #not sure how to return "result" from processFunc.js
```

template.html

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='processFunc.js') }}"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <video id="video" style="display:none"><source src={{url_for('static', filename='videoFile.mp4')}} type="video/mp4"></video>
</body>
</html>
```

processFunc.js

```
$(window).load(function(){
 (function() { 
      someProcess = function(vid){...}
      result = someProcess(document.getElementById('video'));
  })();
});
```

Comment: What is your `result` you want to return?

Comment: Just an array of numbers

Comment: So, turn it into a json object and pass that. There is library support for that on the Python side and it is just js object when received so it should be rather straight forward to use.

Comment: Thank you for the replies, I'm kinda new to flask and javascript. How would I pass the json object back to "/processFile" call? I can send it to another path '/jsvalue' but not sure how to return that back to "/processFile"